# SQLite in Blazor throws duplicate key on insert when it's unique

Tags: sqlite, duplicates, blazor

I am adding records in a table with a text column set as "Unique".
I can add records and get an exception when I try to insert a row with a duplicate text, as expected.

However, after this exception has been raised once, every record I try to add after is "refused" with the duplicate exception, even if there is no duplicate text :(

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the table structure, with the fied name "Json" being the one set to "unique" (Id is an auto-increment integer) :

```
CREATE TABLE MyObjects (
    Id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                                UNIQUE
                                NOT NULL,
    ReferenceClient     TEXT    NOT NULL,
    RaisonSocialeClient TEXT    NOT NULL,
    Json                TEXT    UNIQUE
                                NOT NULL,
    DateFinValidite     TEXT    NOT NULL
);
```

And here is the code used to add records :

```
public async Task<MyObject> AddObjectAsync(MyObject myObject)
{
    try
    {
        dbContext.MyObjects.Add(myObject);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException is SqliteException)
        {
            throw new SqliteException(ex.InnerException.Message, (ex.InnerException as SqliteException).SqliteErrorCode);
        }
        else throw;
    }
    return myObject;
}
```

If I close the program and re-run it again, I can add the record that were throwing the unwanted exception, as expected. The (known) duplicates, for testing purpose, still generate an exception, as expected.
But again, as soon as I have one exception, all the following addition will throw the "duplicate exception", regardless of their content :(

EDIT : here is the exception thrown :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: LicencesSage.Json'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I hope I've been clear enough.

Best regards,
Christophe

Comment: Just some advice - don't post images in questions at stack overflow. Provide the schema (if relevant) in textual form as part of the question (questions with images are frequently downvoted). Aside from that, it seems to me you are 1) adding records to your context, then 2) trying to save the objects and getting an error. But they are still "added" on the client side. So you need to clear these added objects out of your context since they are not valid (not "save-able"). Possibly this means (by extension) that your context is too long-lived - it shouldn't be hanging around for "later use".

Comment: Thank you for your advice about images. I have added the textual description.

The objects are not added, as expected. But it looks like the exception is "not cleared" (I don't find better terms, sorry).
What I understand by reading you, though, is that I should create a new context on each and every addition. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes - that is the "simplest: solution. Helpful reading (maybe): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core in particular pay attention to the special problems with EF Core and blazor, and information about creating contexts and context lifetimes. So in this case (for example) your saved fails, you throw an error so the client/user knows, and you dispose your context. All is well (sort of - couldn't save but oh well).

Comment: Following your advice, I've read the web page you quote and, after some little work, it is now working as expected.
Thank you very much !